# Disable Windows Update during long running processes

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

Occasionally I have to run long running processes on one of my windows server 2012 servers. the processes can sometimes run for over a week. Windows update terminates this processes when it has to reboot.

I am looking for a way to stop the windows updates service programatically while one of these processes is running and re enable windows update after the process is finished. (instead of just disabling windows update on the server).

I have 2 Ideas on possible approaches:

1)use the [ServiceController class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx)

2)call PowerShell commands from my program.

I am not sure on what would be the best solution. or if there is a better option that I am not seeing.

Comment: I'm no expert on windows server. But what about, blocking the access to the windows update server via firewall?

Comment: Windows updates on a server shouldn't automatically re-boot it. At least I have never seen that behaviour. You should look to see if there are any scheduled tasks to re-boot the server and look to disable them rather than windows updates.
However, this won't stop a user (by user I mean someone with permissions), from logging in and rebooting / triggering the Windows Update Reboot manually.

Comment: @Pheonyx normally there is no problem with windows updating and possibly rebooting this server, so that is the present configuration. I am just looking for a way of stopping this behavior when a long running process is being executed. I don't want to disable updates completely so, but i am open to any other options you guys could suggest.

Comment: @BerndGit I don't want to disable windows update permanently, just when one of these processes is running (sometimes I don't have to run them for weeks)

Comment: @Pheonyx: IIRC, on our Windows Server 2008 R2 the default behavior was indeed to [reboot automatically](http://superuser.com/q/190448/25438).

Comment: Windows Updates can be configured [to automatically update but *not* reboot](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc708536). If your service is important enough (and runs for that long) it could take up the responsibility of rebooting the machine at the end of its work cycle. Disabling Windows Update altogether would be possible, but fiddling with that is not a good idea (for example, if your process crashes in the middle, this presumably leaves updates permanently disabled).

Answer (score 1):

2 years ago I had to implement such a feature.

the way to do it is through the windows registry.

you have to edit registry values.

I do remember that Microsoft documentation does not expose all capabilities, has 
some mistakes and they changed some things between windows versions.

*to apply the behaviour, they edit some values and sometime add/delete some(on some of OS you also need to restart the WUA).

this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708449%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (at automatic updates configuration paragraph) contains more information about the registry values.

to solve those problems I played with the windows update agent, by the time i monitored the WUA with [Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

That's how I found most of the problems.

to interact with the registry do:

```
        using (var hive = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,RegistryView.Default))
        using (var key = hive.OpenSubKey(@"put the key there (in most of the operation systems the key is not where microsoft documented)",true))
        {
            //do your logic
        }
```

I can't give you more information because that's will be NDA violation....

hints: after you done I recommend you to force WUA by using the [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @mmilan I forgot to say in my answer that if your organization has WSUS you  can configure through his API and your life will be much easier